# Is .xls workbook template based on dynamic parameters possible?

Tags: excel, templates, parameters, jasper-reports, xls

I'm part of a development team that uses JasperReports in our Java application to generate .pdf or .xls reports. Currently we are trying to extend our .xls reports with predefined print settings and macros.

I discovered the report property [net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.workbook.template](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.workbook.template), whose description seems like a perfect match for this requirement. In our case, the problem now seems to be, that this property cannot be set based on an expression or input parameter (or am I doing it wrong?).

Our server-side architecture (Java) is designed like this: we have a generic JasperReportController, that handles the preparation and exporting of every .jasper/.jrxml file. Reports are populated with default properties and parameters, which the reports designers can use in their reports. Some reports already have dynamic header images, based on language and customer. This was easily implemented with the powerful expression capabilities of JasperReports. But this doesn't seem to be possible with (global) report properties.

What we need:

- A report designer should be able to define a workbook template per report: this one is simple, just define the previously mentioned property on the report
- The specified template should be dynamic, preferably based on an expression (custom function) like: xlsTemplate('my-template.xls', $P{customer}, $P{language}) -> I have no idea how to do this at the moment

This leads to my question: is there a way to specify a report's property as an expression or is there an other approach to solve my requirements?

The solution should be generic, so that a report designer can define the dynamic .xls template just in the .jrxml file and doesn't need to modify Java code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused " property cannot be set based on an expression or input parameter ",  "report designer can define the in jrxml", who is setting it, if in report design just use the property if by parameter see my answer, note  "thePath" can come from any source, even jasper report parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, before you fill your report:

```
String thePath = "... get it from where you like also the jasper report see property map below...."
JRPropertiesMap properties = jasperReport.getPropertiesMap();
properties.put(XlsExporterConfiguration.PROPERTY_WORKBOOK_TEMPLATE,thePath);
```

Conclusion you edit your generic `JasperController`, check if there is a certain property in the report,request url, report name of what ever you prefeer, then in base of your logic set the `PROPERTY_WORKBOOK_TEMPLATE` to the selected template, then fillout the report.